# Manifest merger failed while adding WorkManager as dependency

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin

I'm adding WorkManager as dependency and got stuck in an error. I'm getting error `Manifest merger failed` Please explain what is the problem and how I can solve it.

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-24:19 to override.
```

My build.gradle in main direcory is this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My build.gradle in app directory is this

apply

```
 plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sng.urrsm.calllog"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

I've add `implementation "androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1"` in build.gradle which is present in app directory.

Comment: Move everything to AndroidX. So your `com.android.support` artifacts would become AndroidX equivalents, and you would need to change your uses of those classes to match.

Comment: Please explain how I can do it?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Comment: I have the same issue. I can not migrate to AndroidX easily it's a very big project and it takes too much time to fix some errors that will happen after the migration to AndroidX.